# Message with faye without using database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, faye

Anywhere I look, rails apps that use faye end up storing the message in the database. Is there a way where I don't have to store messages in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faye doesn't store the messages in the database by default. It doesn't even know anything about your database. Try the samples on the Faye website.